# Why do adult soldiers stay under for longer compared to child soldiers?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

Throughout the missions I use a tranq weapon no matter what, I shot both soldiers and child soldiers although child soldiers always wake up a good 5 minutes before the adult soldiers do, why is this?

Comment: Not an answer, but you can move the children to an out-of-the-way location, kick them to wake them up (press CQC button while near a laying down enemy) and hold them up while they're on the ground. They'll remain there unless another enemy spots them or you enter a combat alert (though be careful, I somehow managed to kill a child by kicking them somehow)

Comment: perhaps they use a berry to recover, as they learned this trick from playing a lot of pokemon

Comment: I haven't tested it, but they also seem to get knocked out a lot faster from tranquilzers.  Maybe they have faster metabolisms?

Comment: This question would be better for the format if it asked for a tranq longevity comparison. When asking about game design, it's off topic as the developer's design choice.

Answer (score -1):

There does not appear to be any real answer to this, but it is possible it was to increase the difficulty of sneaking through and detaining the child forces.

Comment: I don't think this is a proper answer here at Arqade. It should be fact-based, not opinion. I'm not downvoting as I'm not sure about this though.

Comment: @Asunez no worries, I don't mind getting downvotes when the community doesn't agree, that's what they are there for, but in all honesty if you really analyze the question they are asking about developer intent which is speculation and the question itself deserves downvotes.